# rsync with date filter

Tags: applescript, rsync

Can rsync be done with a date filter, such that only files newer than some date are transferred? Right now I do rsync using an Applescript and it just backs up all of the files in a remote directory, regardless of date modified. If rsync cannot do date filtering natively, date filtering with Applescript would be acceptable...

Excerpt of current script:

```
do shell script ("rsync -av -f \"+ *.fid\" -f \"- /*\" username@" & server & ":/home/" & user & "/ ~/Documents/" & user & "/RawNMRs/")
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you further explain what you mean by "date filtering"? Also, where are you getting the dates from and what format are they?

Comment: For example, I'd like to only transfer files which have been modified in the last month. I'm hoping that there's a way to use the file's timestamp (the file lives on a linux server).

Comment: Note you can format lines as code by indenting them four spaces. The "101\n010" button in the editor toolbar does this for you. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have stumbled across an answer based on find and piping arguments from [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/205251/rsync-only-files-created-or-modified-after-a-date-and-time). I've also found a better alternative way to solve my specific backup issues, but I thought I'd leave a working date-filtered rsync here for anyone who's interested:

```
ssh username@server "touch -d '2010-12-01 00:00:00' timestampfile"
ssh username@server "find ./*.fid/ -maxdepth 1 -newer timestampfile -print0" | rsync -av --files-from=- username@server:/home/user/ ~/Documents/user/RawNMRs/
```

Comment: This works a little better for me as I just want the newest daily backup file:  
`... find /files/backups/s*.sql -mtime -1 -print | head -n 1 ...`